# How can I get the count to display zero for months that have no records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, recursive-query

I am pulling transactions that happen on an attribute (attribute ID 4205 in table 1235) by the date that a change happened to the attribute (found in the History table) and counting up the number of changes that occurred by month. So far I have

```
SELECT TOP(100) PERCENT MONTH(H.transactiondate) AS Month, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM hsi.rmObjectInstance1235 AS O LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     hsi.rmObjectHistory AS H ON H.objectID = O.objectID 
WHERE H.attributeid = 4205) AND Year(H.transaction date) = '2020' 
GROUP BY MONTH(H.transactiondate)
```

And I get

```
Month    Count 
---------------
1        9 
2        4 
3        11
4        14
5        1
```

I need to display a zero for months June - December instead of excluding those months.

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a recursive query to generate the dates, and then brings the original query with a `left join`:

```
with all_dates as (
    select cast('2020-01-01' as date) dt
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, dt) from all_dates where dt < '2020-12-01'
)
select
    month(d.dt) as month, 
    count(h.objectid) as cnt
from all_dates d
left join hsi.rmobjecthistory as h 
    on  h.attributeid = 4205
    and h.transaction_date >= d.dt
    and h.transaction_date < dateadd(month, 1, d.dt)
    and exists (select 1 from hsi.rmObjectInstance1235 o where o.objectID = h.objectID)
group by month(d.dt)
```

I am quite unclear about the intent of the table `hsi.rmObjectInstance1235` in the query, as none of its column are used in the `select` and `group by` clauses; it it is meant to filter `hsi.rmobjecthistory` by `objectID`, then you can rewrite this as an `exists` condition, as shown in the above solution. Possibly, you might as well be able to just remove that part of the query.

Also, note that

- `top` without `order by` does not really make sense
- `top (100) percent` is a no op

As a consequence, I removed that row-limiting clause.

Comment: 1235 is the table which houses the attribute that we are concerned with the history of. Without that it will not run. I'm giving your solution a try now!

Comment: So, I have to keep the main body of the query the same. Our system requires that the history table be joined with the table itself the way that I have it in the question. That being said, it doesn't run either way.

Comment: @CassandraDurell: are you getting an error? If yes, please share the entire error message.

Comment: Error in list of function arguments: 'COUNT' not recognized. Unable to parse query text.

Comment: @CassandraDurell: against which database are you running this query? I thaught you were running SQL Server, but this doesn't look like a TSQL error message.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @CassandraDurell: this is your client, not your database. Are you running the query against a SQL Server database? Please run `select @@version;` and tell me what it returns.

Comment: @CassandraDurell Are you using the view designer or query designer or something? Try a regular query editor window. Those designers should have been removed from the product years ago.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: @CassandraDurell: ok. This query should just work as it is. Please follow the consignees by Aaron Bertrand to run the query from a regular editor window.

Comment: I will have to use this query in a report builder. I don't have a choice in that matter since my employer dictates this. So, it might return results now but it won't be an option for me later.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try!

Comment: @CassandraDurell: I can't see the rationale for running this query in a report builder only. In any case, such constraint should be clearly mentionned in the question from the start, to avoid the kind of situation we are seeing here.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a difference or I would've said so. I'm new to this.

Comment: If the report builder can call a stored procedure or query a view, you could create a stored procedure or view using an editor that isn't brain dead, then have the report builder call that object instead of needing to (wrongly) try to validate your syntax.